# Why is log(greatest()) so slow?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-performance

We have some complex query that was very slow. I managed to reduce the query to a simple reproduction. It seems that the combination of `greatest` and `log` is the cause, but I don't understand why.

Here is a full [sql-fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/40255) to run the queries - and you can also `View the execution Plans` of the queries (press the link at the bottom of the query result on the sql-fiddle page)

So here is the **slow** query:

```
select count(value)
from (
         SELECT  log(greatest(1e-9, x)) as value
         from (select generate_series(1, 20000, 1) as x) as d
     ) t;
```

We just generate a series of 20k numbers and use `log(greatest())`. This query takes about **1.5** seconds.

I thought that calculating the log may take long, but the following query is also fast (**~5ms**):

```
select count(value)
from (
         SELECT  log(x) as value
         from (select generate_series(1, 20000, 1) as x) as d
     ) t;
```

Just as a test I exchanged `greatest` and `log` - this is also fast (**~5ms**):

```
select count(value)
from (
         SELECT  greatest(1e-9, log(x)) as value
         from (select generate_series(1, 20000, 1) as x) as d
     ) t;
```

The `QUERY PLANS` for all 3 queries are the same:

```
Aggregate (cost=22.51..22.52 rows=1 width=8)
-> Result (cost=0.00..5.01 rows=1000 width=4)
```

**Can anyone explain why the first query is so slow** - and maybe anyone knows a workaround?

## More details

### slow platforms

I get similar results on all of these (first query is a magnitude slower):

- SQL Fiddle uses pg 9.6
- my local PC with similar results: Win10 64bit, pg 11.5 running in Docker
- remote server: Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit running pg 11.5 in Docker
- rextester.com

  - [slow query](https://rextester.com/GKSP6100) ~ 3sec
  - [fast query](https://rextester.com/GKSP6100) ~ 0.5sec

### count

When I change `count(value)` to `count(*)` or `count(1)` (number one) the query is fast

- but this does not help me because the production query does not even include a count
- anyway, I wonder why there is a difference in this case (there are no null-values in the data)

Comment: Btw: `count(1)` is actually [slower than](https://blog.jooq.org/2019/09/19/whats-faster-count-or-count1/) `count(*)` in Postgres

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're invoking two different log functions here: `log(numeric,numeric)` and `log(double precision)`, and the first is much slower than the second.

Notice how the functions call differ in the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE) below,
run with PostgreSQL 11.5 (Linux Ubuntu):

Slow version:

```
explain (analyze, verbose) select count(value)
from (
         SELECT  log(greatest(1e-9, x)) as value
         from (select generate_series(1, 20000, 1) as x) as d
     ) t;
                                              QUERY PLAN                                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=25.02..25.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1174.349..1174.349 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(log('10'::numeric, GREATEST(0.000000001, ((generate_series(1, 20000, 1)))::numeric)))
   ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.02 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.004..1.310 rows=20000 loops=1)
         Output: generate_series(1, 20000, 1)
         ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.123 ms
 Execution Time: 1174.385 ms
```

Fast version:

```
explain (analyze, verbose) select count(value)
from (
         SELECT  log(greatest(1e-9::float, x)) as value
         from (select generate_series(1, 20000, 1) as x) as d
     ) t;
                                                  QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=25.02..25.03 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6.693..6.693 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: count(log(GREATEST('1e-09'::double precision, ((generate_series(1, 20000, 1)))::double precision)))
   ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.02 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=0.004..2.561 rows=20000 loops=1)
         Output: generate_series(1, 20000, 1)
         ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.096 ms
 Execution Time: 6.731 ms
```

`greatest()` is not responsible: considering the query with just `log(x)`, if you cast `x` to `numeric` it will be as slow with or without `greatest()`.